# C# , convert gif data to binary array to image

Tags: c#, arrays, screenshot, gif, imagemagick-convert

this is related with test instrument but need to more help in C# code.
i did more explain here about my question.
i send command to instrument and i just receive data from instrument.
received data is real format (binary) and i just put in to string variable.
here i captured what's inside in string..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcYqV.png

then what i want do is i want this string to convert byte array. because my goal is make png file in my pc. instrument manual said this returned data is gif format but returned real type.'
i believe the problem point is when i convert to byte array,,, there are problem...
does anyone has this kind of experiance,.????

```
            /// below is just send command to instrument that i want " Returns an image of the display in .gif format "
            my6705B.WriteString("hcop:sdump:data?", true);
            string image_format = my6705B.ReadString();
            /// what's inside string image_format ??![i attached screenshot png file. this is what i received from instrument. (manual said this is Returns an image of the display in .gif format)][1] ![png file][2]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcYqV.png

```
          /// now here i think i did something wrong,
          /// the goal is i want change this return data to gif or png or image file.
          /// any solution is ok for me
          /// i just try that change this data to byte array and then try to change image file.
         ///  i think some error here because my code success to convert byte array then create image,,, error
         //// i believe that i did something wrong in convert byte array.....

            System.Text.UnicodeEncoding encode = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] byte_array22 = encode.GetBytes(image_format);

            MemoryStream ms4 = new MemoryStream(byte_array22);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms4);     //// error point
            image.Save(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\imageTest.png");
```

i believe that my explain is in comment.
let me explain again that my goal is convert gif data to image file.
instrument give us Returns an image of the display in .gif format.
i received this data to string array. < i dont know this is correct or not but for now i put to string array > then i just want to png or jpg file with this gif data.

please advice,.

Joseph Choi

Comment: You need to read ASCII string, not 16-bit unicode. Currently encode.GetBytes(image_format) returns something that looks like{ '#','\0','0','\0','G','\0','I','\0','F','\0','8','\0','9','\0' ... }
You either have to use some other API, or convert image_format to ASCII using Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes().

Comment: one thing i can do is now instrument data format is ASC,  so i can change to REAL format.  then we can do another way??

Comment: i think key point is instrument could return asc or real format. so what i did is  format to be asc, then change Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes().  but error in     MemoryStream ms4 = new MemoryStream(byte_array22);
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms4, true, true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try ImageFormat Like

```
image.Save(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\imageTest.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

**Update:**

```
byte[] byte_array22 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(image_format);
MemoryStream ms4 = new MemoryStream(byte_array22);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms4, true, true);
image.Save(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\imageTest.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: but just before that code got error.   Image image = Image.FromStream(ms4);     //// error point   ==> so i think key point is return string,, how can we handle it...

Comment: ya, i did update code but still same error in "Image image = Image.FromStream(ms4, true, true);" so above comment  nitrocaster said need to convert  ASCII string,  so now im trying this

Comment: one thing i can do is now instrument data format is ASC,  so i can change to REAL format.  then we can do another way??

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... here are a couple of methods to transform an image to Base64 format (string), and back.

```
    private string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }

    private Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {

            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }
    }
```

You can use them and play with them to see if they suit you.

I'm not sure that taking an image and simply dumping it into string array will help you much.

Comment: thanks and what i need is Image Base64ToImage.. the thing what i need is the return string could be asc or real,, it means i can choose .... which way i should be use??